# Select statment with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and UNION ALL

Tags: mysql

So I'm  look for data bounded to email and account_id, if it has no result then look for just account_id. The code below doing this correctly.

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS account_id, email, latitude, longitude
 FROM call_module_location
 WHERE email = $email AND `account_id` = $account_id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT account_id, email, latitude, longitude
 FROM call_module_location
 WHERE  FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND `account_id` = $account_id
```

But I need to process 3 case, if data by id not found as well, in this case I should fetch data by email:

```
  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS account_id, email, latitude, longitude
  FROM call_module_location
  WHERE email = $email AND `account_id` = $account_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT account_id, email, latitude, longitude
  FROM call_module_location
  WHERE  FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND `account_id` = $account_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT account_id, email, latitude, longitude
  FROM call_module_location
  WHERE FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND email = $email";
```

But it's not working. Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT account_id, email, latitude, longitude
FROM (SELECT 1 priority, account_id, email, latitude, longitude
      FROM call_module_location
      WHERE email = $email AND `account_id` = $account_id
      UNION
      SELECT 2 priority, account_id, email, latitude, longitude
      FROM call_module_location
      WHERE `account_id` = $account_id
      UNION
      SELECT 3 priority, account_id, email, latitude, longitude
      FROM call_module_location
      WHERE email = $email) u
ORDER BY priority
LIMIT 1
```

It's also possible that your original query will work if you add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to the second query in the `UNION`.